# Swift Optional Unwrapped still crashes

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, nsdictionary, option-type

Relatively new to programming, I understand optional binding and am trying to safely unwrap the dictTemp optional - my understanding is that if sortedResults.objectAtIndex has no value it should just return nil! Instead, it is crashing the app. Optional binding is meant to safeguard the app from crashing so perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to unwrap optionals!

Basically the crash I'm getting is sometimes the sortedResults dictionary is empty, or doesn't contain enough entries to loop the correct number of times. I'd like it to return nil instead of just crashing.

```
    var mainArrOfDict:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "SortingNumber", ascending: false)
    var subDescriptor1: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "TotalCount", ascending: false)
    var subDescriptor2: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ArrayLength", ascending: true)
    var sortedResults: NSArray = mainArrOfDict.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor,subDescriptor1,subDescriptor2])

func SortingArray(sortingArray : NSArray, maxLimit : Int , minLimit : Int) -> NSMutableArray
    var usersSelectedString: String = User.currentUser.getCount() as String
    var usersSelectedInt: Int? = usersSelectedString.toInt()       
    for var j=0 ; j < usersSelectedInt; j++ {

        // ** Crash highlights the line below
        if let dictTemp : NSDictionary = sortedResults.objectAtIndex(j) as? NSDictionary {

            if let strTotalCount : AnyObject  = dictTemp.objectForKey("index") {
                arrFinalArray.addObject(finalArrayToSort.objectAtIndex(Int(strTotalCount as! NSNumber)))

            }
        }
    }

    return arrFinalArray
}
```

Console log from crash:
2015-07-05 18:18:38.636 sliced[758:126835] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: where/how do you declare "sortedResults"?

Comment: added the code in the question. To save everyone the headache though I'm only going back as far as I think the context is necessary!

Comment: You might want to post the console output from the crash, too. That'll give readers a little more color re: what's happening.

Comment: The problem would appear that `usersSelectedInt` is some number greater than zero, but the error is telling you that `sortedResults` is empty. Frankly, in your code sample, you show us that `sortedResults` is a sorted version of `mainArrOfDict` which you just initialized as an empty array. Bottom line, check to make sure that `usersSelectedInt` is less than `sortedResults.count` before you start iterating through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message now says that you have an empty array and attempt to access element at position 0, which is out of bounds. Crash in this situation is [expected](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:).

In general, I would suggest breaking down the complex line into individual lines with one operation each. It will be easier to spot the problem during debugging and it will also allow you to add some checks to the code.

Comment: good point, however i'm still getting the crash! I'll add the new if let statement to the original question

Comment: Yes, but the error referenced in the question is related to array, not this dictionary.

Comment: @Rob I'm quite certain the error is that the sortedResults.objectAtIndex(j) has no value. The array that's trying to be accessed (sortedResults) doesn't have any entries in it. My question would that if it has no value, why is it crashing? Shouldn't it just return nil?

Comment: @Chris - No, if your index passed to `objectAtIndex` exceeds the the number of items in the array, it will crash, producing the error in your question. When you call `objectAtIndex`, you are responsible for ensuring you don't use an index that exceeds the range of indexes that are permissible for the array. In this case, the array is empty, so when the code tries to retrieve the item at index zero, you crash.